# Conversion FASTA to BED fails

Tags: format-conversion, python

I want to use [conform-gt](https://faculty.washington.edu/browning/conform-gt.html) to get rid of some REF prefix differences see [here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/19977/large-amount-of-ref-prefix-differences-after-lifting?noredirect=1#comment29310_19977). Conform-gt needs the reference FASTA file split by chromosome and in .vcf.gz format. How can I do this?

I already tried `faidx` with

```
faidx --transform bed reference/GRCh38_full_analysis_set_plus_decoy_hla.fa > reference/GRCh38_full_analysis_set_plus_decoy_hla.bed
```

but this produced the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/oem/.local/bin/faidx", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/oem/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyfaidx/cli.py", line 202, in main
    write_sequence(args)
  File "/home/oem/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyfaidx/cli.py", line 51, in write_sequence
    outfile.write(transform_sequence(args, fasta, name, start, end))
  File "/home/oem/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyfaidx/cli.py", line 121, in transform_sequence
    line_len = fasta.faidx.index[name].lenc
KeyError: 'HLA-A*01'
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and explain what you mean a bit more? Your title talks about converting fasta (sequences) to bed (regions) which is odd, but could be done if you mean "read the fasta and tell me what regions of a reference genome they map to". But then your question talks about converting fasta to "vcf.gz" format and this doesn't make sense unless you want some sort of gVCF file with an entry for every position of a genome.

Comment: I reconsidered my question. I don't think that I really fully understood what I want to achieve with this format-conversion nor if I really understood what conform-gt really does. Back to the drawing board I guess. I will close this question and hope that the original question in my OP can solve my problem.